# PHP Mysql Query Troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql

Novice PHP/Mysql user here... hoping someone can help me make this bit of code run a lot faster.  Trying to do a simple calculation of football team's offensive and defensive averages for season-to-date... in ms excel this takes less than 10 seconds with sumifs.  With the bit of code posted below using php/mysql it takes 3 hours!  I know I can do some things better... just not sure what!  Thanks.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE nfl_new SET Season = if(MONTH(date)<5, YEAR(date)-1,YEAR(date))");
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM nfl_new";

        if (!$results = mysql_query($sql,$con))
            {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            } 

        $num = mysql_numrows($results);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $num) {
        //get a row from mysql one at a time    
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($results, $i);

        //calculate aw teams's offense
        $awscoreaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(aw_score) AS awscoreaw FROM nfl_new WHERE away='$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $awgames = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if((away = '$row[away]' OR home = '$row[away]') AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgames FROM nfl_new");
        $awgamesaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(away = '$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgamesaw FROM nfl_new");
        $awgameshm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(home = '$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgameshm FROM nfl_new");
        $awscorehm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hm_score) AS awscorehm FROM nfl_new WHERE home='$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $awscoreaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($awscoreaw);
        $awscorehm = mysql_fetch_assoc($awscorehm);
        $awgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgames);
        $awgamesaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgamesaw);
        $awgameshm = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgameshm);
        $aw_off = ($awscoreaw['awscoreaw'] + $awscorehm['awscorehm']+$awgamesaw['awgamesaw']*1.5-$awgameshm['awgameshm']*1.5)/$awgames['awgames'];

        //calculate aw teams's defense
        $awscoreaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hm_score) AS awscoreaw FROM nfl_new WHERE away='$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $awgames = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if((away = '$row[away]' OR home = '$row[away]') AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgames FROM nfl_new");
        $awgamesaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(away = '$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgamesaw FROM nfl_new");
        $awgameshm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(home = '$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgameshm FROM nfl_new");
        $awscorehm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(aw_score) AS awscorehm FROM nfl_new WHERE home='$row[away]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $awscoreaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($awscoreaw);
        $awscorehm = mysql_fetch_assoc($awscorehm);
        $awgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgames);
        $awgamesaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgamesaw);
        $awgameshm = mysql_fetch_assoc($awgameshm);
        $aw_def = ($awscoreaw['awscoreaw'] + $awscorehm['awscorehm']-$awgamesaw['awgamesaw']*1.5+$awgameshm['awgameshm']*1.5)/$awgames['awgames'];

        //calculate hm teams's offense
        $hmscoreaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(aw_score) AS awscoreaw FROM nfl_new WHERE away='$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $hmgames = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if((away = '$row[home]' OR home = '$row[home]') AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgames FROM nfl_new");
        $hmgamesaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(away = '$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgamesaw FROM nfl_new");
        $hmgameshm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(home = '$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgameshm FROM nfl_new");
        $hmscorehm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hm_score) AS awscorehm FROM nfl_new WHERE home='$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $hmscoreaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmscoreaw);
        $hmscorehm = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmscorehm);
        $hmgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgames);
        $hmgamesaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgamesaw);
        $hmgameshm = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgameshm);
        $hm_off = ($hmscoreaw['awscoreaw'] + $hmscorehm['awscorehm']+$hmgamesaw['awgamesaw']*1.5-$hmgameshm['awgameshm']*1.5)/$hmgames['awgames'];

        //calculate hm teams's defense
        $hmscoreaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hm_score) AS awscoreaw FROM nfl_new WHERE away='$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $hmgames = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if((away = '$row[home]' OR home = '$row[home]') AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgames FROM nfl_new");
        $hmgamesaw = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(away = '$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgamesaw FROM nfl_new");
        $hmgameshm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(if(home = '$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]', 1, 0)) AS awgameshm FROM nfl_new");
        $hmscorehm = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(aw_score) AS awscorehm FROM nfl_new WHERE home='$row[home]' AND date<'$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");
        $hmscoreaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmscoreaw);
        $hmscorehm = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmscorehm);
        $hmgames = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgames);
        $hmgamesaw = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgamesaw);
        $hmgameshm = mysql_fetch_assoc($hmgameshm);
        $hm_def = ($hmscoreaw['awscoreaw'] + $hmscorehm['awscorehm']-$hmgamesaw['awgamesaw']*1.5+$hmgameshm['awgameshm']*1.5)/$hmgames['awgames'];




        mysql_query("UPDATE nfl_new SET aw_off='$aw_off', aw_def='$aw_def', hm_off='$hm_off', hm_def='$hm_def' WHERE away='$row[away]' AND date='$row[date]' AND Season='$row[Season]'");

        echo $row['date'].' '.$row['away'].' '.$aw_def.'<br />';
        ob_flush();
    flush(); 
        $i++;   
        }
```

Here's the output from SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
 nfl_new    CREATE TABLE `nfl_new` (
 `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `away` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `aw_line` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `home` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `hm_line` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `total` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `aw_score` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_score` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_firstdown` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_firstdown` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_rush_att` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_rush_att` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_rush_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_rush_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_pass_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_pass_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_ret_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_ret_yds` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_pass_comp` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_pass_comp` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_pass_att` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_pass_att` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_int` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_int` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_sacks` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_sacks` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_sack_yds` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_sack_yds` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_fum` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_fum` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_fum_lost` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_fum_lost` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_pen` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `hm_pen` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `aw_pen_yds` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `hm_pen_yds` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `aw_fg_att` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_fg_att` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_fg` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `hm_fg` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `aw_top` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `hm_top` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `Season` year(4) NOT NULL,
 `aw_off` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_def` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_off` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_def` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_mov` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_mov` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_sos` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_sos` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_sim` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_sim` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_ypp_off` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_ypp_def` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_ypp_off` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_ypp_def` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_ypp_mov` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_ypp_mov` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_ypp_sos` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_ypp_sos` double NOT NULL,
 `aw_ypp_sim` double NOT NULL,
 `hm_ypp_sim` double NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6733 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Thats allot of querys alone, multiplying that by how many teams, 3 hours is about right ;p.

Comment: What is the structure of the table and how many rows are in it?  Some of the queries can be combined, but more information will help.

Comment: There are 6600 rows in the table.  Most columns are varchar, ints, or doubles.

Comment: @user1043610 Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`.

Comment: Am I seeing things, or are the $awgamesXXX queries the same in all four blocks?

Comment: Edited my post to include show/create table.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're doing, but I think this combines everything into one query:

```
SELECT n2.date, n2.season, n2.away,
       SUM(n2.away IN (n1.away, n1.home)) AS awgames,
       SUM(n2.home IN (n1.away, n1.home)) AS hmgames,
       SUM(n2.away = n1.away) AS awgamesaw,
       SUM(n2.away = n1.home) AS awgameshm,
       SUM(n2.home = n1.away) AS hmgamesaw,
       SUM(n2.home = n1.home) AS hmgameshm,
       SUM(IF(n2.away = n1.away, aw_score)) AS awgamesaw_awscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.away = n1.away, hm_score)) AS awgamesaw_hmscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.away = n1.home, aw_score)) AS awgameshm_awscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.away = n1.home, hm_score)) AS awgameshm_hmscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.home = n1.away, aw_score)) AS hmgamesaw_awscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.home = n1.away, hm_score)) AS hmgamesaw_hmscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.home = n1.home, aw_score)) AS hmgameshm_awscore,
       SUM(IF(n2.home = n1.home, hm_score)) AS hmgameshm_hmscore,
FROM nfl_new n1 JOIN nfl_new n2
ON n1.date < n2.date AND n1.season = n2.season AND (n2.home IN (n1.home, n1.away) OR n2.away IN (n1.home, n1.away))
GROUP BY n2.date, n2.season, n2.away
```

I'm not sure about the grouping, though. Your original queries aren't grouped, but when it prints the results it only prints the date, season, and away from the first query, so that seems to be the way you're thinking of it.

The reason it's taking so long (beside the duplicated queries) is that it seems to be a quadratic computation. You're looping over all the rows returned by the first query, and for each of those rows you're summing all the rows preceding it in the season. That's a lot of repetition.

It might be better to do a query that returns all the rows sorted by season and date, and calculate running totals in the PHP code. It's also possible to do that directly in SQL using user-defined variables. I'm too tired now to try to write that version of the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Sorry about the confusing printout of date, season, away... that was just an error checking mechanism I had in the code.  I'm going to try to implement your code now and see if it helps... good idea about using php to do the calcs.